# Why are my "Sleep" settings disabled?

Tags: settings

Under 'Settings - > Display', my 'Sleep' option is disabled and locked at 30 seconds (which is terrible). I have a 'Work Profile' on the phone, but this is not happening to others at the company, so this appears to be a local issue.

What could be causing this and how can I re-enable my sleep settings? It seems some other setting is affecting the sleep setting, but I can't find what it would be.

Answer (score 4):

I'd manually activated the 'Battery'->'Power Saving' mode, which was overriding the 'Sleep' settings. It would be nice if the 'Sleep' settings had told me this, but there you go.